# How to disable public transport icons in GoogleMaps for Android v2?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I'm afraid the answer is: You can't, but I think, asking won't hurt.

My client is a public transport company and they want a visualization of all of their bus stops on a map. Problem is: Their GPS measurements don't line up with the icons that are "baked into" the map from Google by default.

Does anyone know, how to disable these icons on purpose? The only thing I could find in the API to manipulate the look of the map was [this very limited option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMapType%28int%29) to go toggle between street, terrain and satellite views. As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=en#change_the_map_type), that doesn't do the trick.

I figure, if I want to achieve what I want to, I need to adopt an open street maps widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't currently. There is a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4841) already for that.

You may want to try satellite. Link you have put shows hybrid (satellite + roads and things like that).